# Aggregating a timestamped zoo object by clock time (i.e. not solely by time in the zoo object)

Tags: r, aggregation, zoo

I have a zoo object which consists of a timestamped (to the second) timeseries. The timeseries is irregular in that the time intervals between the values are not regularly spaced.

I would like to transform the irregularly spaced timeseries object into a regularly spaced one, where the time intervals between values is a constant - say 15 minutes, and are "real world" clock times.

Some sample data may help illustrate further

```
# Sample data
2011-05-05 09:30:04 101.32
2011-05-05 09:30:14 100.09
2011-05-05 09:30:19 99.89
2011-05-05 09:30:35 89.66
2011-05-05 09:30:45 95.16
2011-05-05 09:31:12 100.28
2011-05-05 09:31:50 100.28
2011-05-05 09:32:10 98.28
```

I'd like to aggregate them (using my custom function) for every specified time period (e.g. 30 second time bucket) such that the output looks like the table presented below.

The key is that I want to aggregate every 30 seconds by clock time NOT 30 seconds starting from my first observation time. Naturally, the first time bucket would be the first time bucket for which I have a recorded observation (i.e. row) in the data to be aggregated.

```
2011-05-05 09:30:00   101.32
2011-05-05 09:30:30   89.66
2011-05-05 09:31:00   100.28
```

In the example given, my custom aggregate function simply returns the first value in the 'set' of 'selected rows' to aggregate  over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read in the data and then aggregate it by minute:

```
Lines <- "2011-05-05 09:30:04 101.32
2011-05-05 09:30:14 100.09
2011-05-05 09:30:19 99.89
2011-05-05 09:30:35 89.66
2011-05-05 09:30:45 95.16
2011-05-05 09:31:12 100.28
2011-05-05 09:31:50 100.28
2011-05-05 09:32:10 98.28"

library(zoo)
library(chron)
toChron <- function(d, t) as.chron(paste(d, t))
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, index = 1:2, FUN = toChron)
aggregate(z, trunc(time(z), "00:01:00"), mean)
```

The result is:

```
(05/05/11 09:30:00) (05/05/11 09:31:00) (05/05/11 09:32:00) 
             97.224             100.280              98.280
```

Comment: Succinct code ... almost there, but I want to aggregate by every 30 seconds not by every minute.

Comment: Replace the reference to one minute with 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I hope we can assume this is in a zoo or xts object. If so then try this:

```
  # First get a start for a set of intervals, need to use your tz
beg<- as.POSIXct( format(index(dat[1,]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="EST5EDT"))
  # Then create a sequence of 30 second intervals
tseq <- beg+seq(0,4*30, by=30)
  # Then this will creat a vector than you can use for your aggregation fun
findInterval(index(dat), tseq)
  #[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 5
  # To find the first row in a subset of rows from tapply, try "[" with 1
tapply(dat, findInterval(index(dat), tseq), "[", 1)
  #     1      2      3      4      5 
  #101.32  89.66 100.28 100.28  98.28
```

Comment: It would never have occured to me to try this approach. Interesting ... BTW, could you explain why you are using 4*30 in creating the sequence. I don't understand that part.

Comment: You need an ending time that is greater than your last observation. If you wanted to calculate that (and you probably should), then you would need to use max(index(dat))+30 to make sure that the interval vector for findInterval was sufficiently long.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply truncate the times towards your interval, so assuming `t` is the time (use `as.POSIXct` if it's not)

```
bucket = t - as.numeric(t) %% 30
```

then you can aggregate over `bucket`, like `aggregate(value, list(bucket), sum)`

(I don't use `zoo` so this is with pure R)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `align.time` in `xts`. It does something very close to what you want to achieve.

```
my.data <- read.table(text="date,x
2011-05-05 09:30:04,101.32
2011-05-05 09:30:14,100.09
2011-05-05 09:30:19,99.89
2011-05-05 09:30:35,89.66
2011-05-05 09:30:45,95.16
2011-05-05 09:31:12,100.28
2011-05-05 09:31:50,100.28
2011-05-05 09:32:10,98.28", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE,sep = ",")

my.data <- xts(my.data[,2],as.POSIXlt(my.data[,1],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

library(xts)
res <-align.time(my.data,30)
res[!duplicated(index(res)),]

                      [,1]
2011-05-05 09:30:30 101.32
2011-05-05 09:31:00  89.66
2011-05-05 09:31:30 100.28
2011-05-05 09:32:00 100.28
2011-05-05 09:32:30  98.28
```

You can lag the time series by 30 seconds if it makes the interpretation clearer.

Comment: Am I missing something?. I don't see where the (custom) aggregation is being done ... The results appear correct, but I cant see how that was achieved using the snippet above

Comment: You didn't tell us how you wanted to aggregate (mean, VWAP...). I did the same thing you did: chose only the first trade per 30 second block. This is what `!duplicated` does.